# Syntax to run CPanel cron job with query string?

Tags: cron, cpanel

I've tried every variation I can think of but can't seem to get my script to execute.  I can hit it manually and it runs fine, but I'd prefer to have an outside server just hit it once per day.  Is the trouble I'm having due to the presence of a query string?

My script URL looks like:

http://domain.com/index.php?g=main&reset=true

I've tried curl, wget, lynx, GET... all with no result whatsoever.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Aha... knew it had to be something simple.  Was missing quotes around the URL!  Final working line in CPanel is:

`wget -O - "http://domain.com/index.php?g=main&reset=true" >/dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply do like this in `Cron Jobs`

```
/usr/bin/curl --user-agent cPanel-Cron "http://example.com/index.php?g=main&reset=true"
```